# Returning pointer-to-member-function (without typedefs)

Tags: c++, c++03, member-functions, pointer-to-member

Compiling on C++03, I've attempted to write up a test template function that returns a pointer-to-member-function of a member function that returns int, and takes two float arguments:

```
template<typename TemplateClass>
int (TemplateClass::*)(float,float) Testtest(TemplateClass &A)
{
    return &TemplateClass::Function;
}
```

But naturally, no matter what variations on the pointer-to-member-function syntax I use, the compiler complains of initialisation errors. Typedef, although it works with known classes, for obvious reasons (naming conflicts), won't accept template class arguments for classes that I can't know ahead of time which are likely to use the same function.

What non-typedef way is there to get this function to compile and return a pointer-to-member-function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To declare it without a type alias, without type deduction, and without a trailing return type:

```
template<typename TemplateClass>
int (TemplateClass::* Testtest(TemplateClass &A))(float,float)
```

But of course this isn't what you would use in real code. Instead you would use an [alias template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

```
template<typename T>
using return_type = int (T::*)(float,float);

template<typename TemplateClass>
return_type<TemplateClass> Testtest(TemplateClass &A)
```

Or return type deduction in C++14:

```
template<typename TemplateClass>
auto Testtest(TemplateClass &A)
```

Or a trailing return type (in C++11):

```
template<typename TemplateClass>
auto Testtest(TemplateClass &A) -> int (TemplateClass::*)(float,float)
```

Comment: Well, I would have never have guessed the first one. It's so... convoluted. C++, why you do this?!

Comment: @c1646091 That syntax is inherited from C.

Comment: C, why you do this?!

Answer (score 3):

You need this prototype:

```
template<typename TemplateClass>
int (TemplateClass::*Testtest(TemplateClass &A)) (float,float) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
  int (Class::*f())(float,float);
```

`f` is function taking no arguments returning pointer to member function of class `Class` takinf 2 floats and returning int.

And template version:

```
         template <typename Type>
         int (Type::*f())(float,float);
```

Answer (score 0):

I reject the premise of your question. Use typedefs. Or, specifically, a type trait:

```
template <class T, class F>
struct make_mem_fun {
    typedef F T::*type;
};

template<typename TemplateClass>
typename make_mem_fun<TemplateClass, int(float, float)>::type
Testtest(TemplateClass &A)
{
    return &TemplateClass::Function;
}
```

That is way easier to understand than the convoluted syntax of actually returning the type. With C++11, we can turn that into an alias to drop the `typename ::type` stuff.

Comment: *Why* do you reject the premise of the question? Typedefs, as said, don't work with templates - as evidenced by your usage of a struct as a sort of work around. I'd personally prefer to know what the syntax of a function returning a pointer-to-member-function looks like rather than burying my ignorance in a weird 'always typedef' workaround, not only so I can implement it, but so I can also identify it as well. The knowledge is so well buried even multiple searches couldn't dig it up, experimenting failed and I was forced to ask on SO.

Comment: @c1646091 Can you at a glance understand what `int (TemplateClass::* Testtest(TemplateClass &A))(float,float)` means? It'd take me 10 minutes just to parse that. Understanding what `make_mem_fun<TemplateClass, int(float, float)>` means? Piece of cake.

Comment: @c1646091 And as my answer shows, typedefs do work with templates. This is a C++03 template typedef. It becomes less verbose in C++11, but it's not like it doesn't exist.